# Bulk Vertical update of Aurora MySQL column values

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-aurora

So I am using Aurora MYSQL DB, and my AWS Lambda instance needs to do the following.
Assume a table with two columns, ID, and Translated ID.
I have acess to a Lambda function, which takes the ID as input, and outputs the Translated ID. It can also take a list of IDs, and give back list of translated IDs.
The problem is right now, I am doing it row by row with the workflow as:
1. get top 100 Rows from table, where translated ID is null, 
2. for each row, retrieve the ID, use the API to get the translated ID.
3. Update the row with the translated id.
4. rinse and repeat for all 100 rows.

The problem is due to the latency of involving the api in between, the row by row operaton is causing the lambda function to timeout. Is there any way to do a batch operation, while still aligning the translated IDS, vertically with the corresponding IDs?. Something like:

1. get top 100 IDS from table, where translated ID is null.
2. Use the API to take the list of all 100 IDS, and get a corresponding list of 100 translated IDs.
3. Pefro, (in one single update command preferably) update all the 100 ID rows, with their corresponding Translated-id column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4 queries:

(0). ensure the environment is clean (you can omit this one if you are never reusing a database connection).

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS my_updates;
```

(1). Create a temp table to hold the new values.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE my_updates (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  translated_id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

(2). Insert all the new values in a bulk insert.

```
INSERT INTO my_updates (id, translated_id)
VALUES (?,?), (?,?), (?,?), ...
```

Repeat `(?,?)` × 100.  Pass an array of 200 elements to this query.  Some MySQL libraries have shortcuts for multiple row inserts, others you need to build the row parameter placeholder sets.

(3). You now have all 100 new tuples on the server, so you can ask it to update... join.

```
UPDATE base_table b
  JOIN my_updates m ON m.id = b.id
   SET b.translated_id = m.translated_id;
```

---

You could also do this in one query, though it is a little more convoluted:

```
UPDATE base_table
   SET translated_id = CASE id
       WHEN @i1 THEN @ti1
       WHEN @i2 THEN @ti2
       ...
       WHEN @i100 THEN @ti100
       ELSE translated_id END
 WHERE id IN (@i1,@i2,...@i100);
```

I've used @value here as placeholders to explain what goes where, since it would be less intuitive than the example above, but this query should actually be done with `?` placeholders as well.  The argument passed would be an array of 300 members, with 100 sets of (id,translated_id) and then all of the (id) values again for the `WHERE`.  The `ELSE` is a safety precaution... it should never actually be reached, but no data will be overwritten if it is.